# Is it possible to make a POST request to Slack with AWS Lambda using only native libraries?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, http-post, webhooks

I am trying to make a POST request to Slack using webhooks. I can send a curl to my Slack instance locally but when trying to do so in lambda I run into trouble trying to send the payload.

Everything I've seen says I must use and zip custom libraries but for the purposes of what I'm doing I need to use native python code. Is there a way to send this POST request?

```
import json
import urllib.request
#import botocore.requests as requests

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  message=event['message']
  response = urllib.request.urlopen(message) 
  print(response)
```

This code gives me a 400 error which is how I know I'm hitting the URL I want (URL is in the message variable) but every attempt at sending a payload by adding headers and a text body seems to fail.

Comment: Without the "data" parameter, the request method is considered as GET, instead of POST. Check [here](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen).

Comment: Changed the parameter to data, still have a 400 error.

Comment: 1) add data(_dict_) to make post request.
2) convert data serialized obj to a JSON formatted str and then encode it with ascii formatted 
`data = json.dumps(data).encode('ascii')`

Answer (score 0):

You may try as below:

```
SLACK_URL = 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/....'

req = urllib.request.Request(SLACK_URL, json.dumps(message).encode('utf-8'))
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same Bad Request 400 error which means the payload isn't sending properly.

Comment: encode should be ascii type. `json.dumps(message).encode('ascii')`

Comment: @SupratimSamantray - how do you decode the response?

Answer (score 0):

- Please find attached lambda_handler code, hope this helps you.
- All the messages to be posted on slack are put on a SNS topic which in turn is read by a lambda and posted to the slack channel using the slack webhook url.

```
import os
import json
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, URLError, HTTPError

# Get the environment variables
SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL = os.environ['SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL']
SLACK_CHANNEL = os.environ['SLACK_CHANNEL']
SLACK_USER = os.environ['SLACK_USER']

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Read message posted on SNS Topic
    message = json.loads(event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message'])

# New slack message is created
    slack_message = {
        'channel': SLACK_CHANNEL,
        'username': SLACK_USER,
        'text': "%s" % (message)
    }
# Post message on SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL
    req = Request(SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL, json.dumps(slack_message))
    try:
        response = urlopen(req)
        response.read()
        print(slack_message['channel'])
    except HTTPError as e:
        print(e)
    except URLError as e:
        print(e)
```